# ASP MVC 4, passing data in custom editor template

Tags: c#, razor, html-helper

I'm using this line of code to call a custom editor template.

```
@Html.Editor("country", "CustomDropdown", CountrySelectionList)
```

I'd now like to access `CountrySelectionList` in the CustomDropdown view and iterate over its items: how can I do that?
**CountrySelectionList is of type [SelectList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).**

This is what I tried to do in the view:

```
@model SelectList

@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
    <div>@item.ToString()</div>
}
```

But got an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error.

So how can I do that? I'd like to do my own dropdown list: this is impossible without iterating over the key + value pairs of the SelectList.

Comment: put select list items into the <option> element. why using div?

Comment: because it is just a test: obviously I'll change that when it will work.

Comment: both of your codes are at the same page?

Comment: No - one is the main view, the other is /Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/CustomDropdown.cshtml

Comment: When you debug, are you able to verify that `CountrySelectionList` is not null and contains items? You'll get this error is the model itself is null or its `Items` collection is null.

Comment: show CountrySelectionList class.

Comment: Good idea to use the debbuger! I've found that Model, in the view, arrives null while CustomerCountrySelectionList is correctly retrieved from dataRepository as a selectList - my question is: how do I pass the selectList in the view? I assume I'm doing in the wrong way.

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi here it is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: this is the base class for select list. show CountrySelectionList class.

Comment: Quoting from the question: "CountrySelectionList is of type SelectList".

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/CustomDropdown.cshtml", CustomerCountrySelectionList)
```

And the models goes straight into the view.

`@Html.Editor()`, despite having 6 overloads, probably have none of them designed to pass a model inside the custom editor.